# Opposite of "bells and whistles"

Tags: antonyms

*Bells and whistles* refers to *non-essential features, visual or functional, that are an enhancement to the object*. What is the opposite of *bells and whistles*?

Comment: "bare essentials" or "bread and butter"

Comment: you quote says "Bells and whistles refers to non-essential features". Clearly the opposite is *essential features*.

Comment: I would say the "bear bones"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would call those the *[nuts and bolts](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/nuts+and+bolts)*.

> 1. Fig. the mundane workings of something; the basics of something. (See also [get down to the nuts and bolts](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+down+to+the+nuts+and+bolts).)
>      
>    *I want you to learn how to
>      write well. You have to know the nuts and bolts of writing. She's got
>      a lot of good, general ideas, but when it comes to the nuts and bolts
>      of getting something done, she's no good.*

Comment: *'Nuts and bolts'* refers to the *down and dirty* details of something which is not quite the same thing as *'table stakes'* or *'meat and potatoes'*

Answer (score 13):

I would say that things that are opposites of *bells and whistles* (that is, they are not optional) are *essential* (adj.) or *essentials* (noun). Another noun that would work is *necessity*.

Edit: Since a more metaphorical example was asked for, I shall provide one that I think fits decently: *meat and potatoes*. The *meat and potatoes* are the basic, necessary things; this is the opposite of *bells and whistles*.

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking for a more metaphorical opposite if such exists.

Comment: @YuriyZubarev Edited to add that.

Comment: @Mahnax: "Meat and potatoes?" Are you sure this is standard usage? I'm sure it _exists_, but honestly, how many people around the world actually eat meat and potatoes to know that it's supposed to be "basic"?

Comment: @YuriyZubarev: honestly, I think you'd be better off sticking with "essentials". As I said, people might not immediately grasp what you're referring to otherwise. Is there a reason you want only a metaphorical term?

Comment: @MilindGanjoo: I've heard the phrase "meat and potatoes" often enough to think it's a fitting antonym for "bells and whistles": along the same lines and metaphorical (hence +1 from me). "Essentials" would be more appropriate for "enhancements".

Comment: A quick search online gave me a definition only in the American Heritage Dictionary, and it was marked as informal usage. Is it possible that it's only a North American term? Can anyone else confirm if it's standard usage elsewhere as well?

Comment: I would say "bare bones"

Comment: @MilindGanjoo: I'm Australian, and it's definitely used over here as well.

Comment: Well then, I learnt a new phrase today :) I never heard it growing up in India. I wonder if it could be due to the culturally non-staple nature of meat and potatoes there. (it could be just me of course)

Answer (score 5):

Having lived on both sides of the Atlantic, I can confirm that 'meat and potatoes' is used not only by North Americans, but also by English-speakers across the pond. I believe both 'meat and potatoes' and 'bare bones' work in this context.

Answer (score 4):

*Brass tacks* means the fundamental or essential elements. It is often used as "let's get down to brass tacks." [Phrase defined](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/get-down-to-brass-tacks.html)

Another option is *nitty-gritty*, which means the essentials or basics. [Merriam-Webster definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nitty-gritty)

Answer (score 3):

The company I work for uses the term ***"table stakes"***

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_stakes):

> In business, *table stakes* also refers to the minimum entry requirement for a market or business arrangement. It can refer to pricing, cost models, technology, or other capability that represents a minimum requirement to have a credible competitive starting position in a market or other business arrangement. For example, if you want to be a Wireless service provider the table stakes are the basic features you need to have in order to be in that business to achieve foundation capability - Network, Handsets, a data service, a mail server, etc. Beyond that, real competitive advantage comes from additional nimbleness and cost or product differentiation.

Answer (score 3):

There are many different answers, all of which is good.  One of the comments is close as well; "bare bones."  Not bear (the animal) bones.

Answer (score 2):

I guess I am the lone voice of dissent, but I would argue that *meat and potatoes* and *bare bones* have a slightly different intent and connotation. *Bare bones* I think is a perfect antonym to *bells and whistles*, while *meat and potatoes*, not so much.

My take:

*Bells and whistles* - Describes non-essential add-ons but does NOT seem pejorative in meaning.  I'd say a car with SatNav, leather seats and satellite radio had *all the bells and whistles* but I would certainly not mean that those extras were frivolous. *All the bells and whistles* sounds generally positive to me.

*Bare bones* sounds just slightly pejorative to me. *Bare bones* comes off to me as if you would take more *bells and whistles* if they were an option.  If I wanted a *bare bones* car it would be just transportation, without the extra because I couldn't or wouldn't pay for them.

As opposed to Meat and Potatoes, which while close, sounds a little more positive.  Meat and potatoes sounds to me like I want to keep it simple, and view sticking to the functional heart of something as preferable.

I buy a Mustang with *all the bells and whistles* because I can afford to splurge.
I buy a *bare bones* Mustang because I can't afford more, or intend to do all the upgrades myself.
I buy a *meat and potatoes* Mustang because I like a straight up simple functional performance car and don't want or need all those frivolous add-ons.

Just my personal feeling when I hear those terms.  On a side note, where I am from, I think the most common direct antonym to *bells and whistles* is "no-frills".